# How to use collapsible div tags in WordPress

Tags: javascript

I have a client running Google Ads. They have mobile ads that do not show up unless on mobile. The problem is, they still take up space on desktop browsers. The Google Ad contact keeps referring us to this page: https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/3419382?hl=en

I have it placed in the  script:

```
<script type=’text/javascript’>
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function() {
var gads = document.createElement(‘script’);
gads.async = true;
gads.type = ‘text/javascript';
var useSSL = ‘https:’ == document.location.protocol;
gads.src = (useSSL ? ‘https:’ : ‘http:’) +
‘//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
var node = document.getElementsByTagName(‘script’)[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
</script>

<script type=’text/javascript’>
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
googletag.defineSlot(‘/50217444/Momsnacks_160x600′, [160, 600],   ‘div-gpt-ad-1427162132059-0′).addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot(‘/50217444/Momsnacks_300x250′, [300, 250], ‘div-gpt-ad-1427162132059-1′).addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot(‘/50217444/Momsnacks_300x250(mobile)’, [300, 250], ‘div-gpt-ad-1427162132059-2′).addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot(‘/50217444/Momsnacks_320x100(mobile)’, [320, 100], ‘div-gpt-ad-1427162132059-3′).addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot(‘/50217444/Momsnacks_320x50(mobile)’, [320, 50], ‘div-gpt-ad-1427162132059-4′).addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot(‘/50217444/MomSnacks_728x90′, [728, 90], ‘div-gpt-ad-1427162132059-5′).addService(googletag.pubads());
.setCollapseEmptyDiv(true); //Collapsible div–Collapse this slot before ad fetch
googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>
```

Specifically, this code was added: .setCollapseEmptyDiv(true); //Collapsible div–Collapse this slot before ad fetch

You’ll see the ads are not generating, but the space is still parked. The Google contact is basically no help and I have no idea how to get it to collapse when ads do not show. I have it on a test site that is Genesis Magazine theme out of the box.

http://celebrouhaha.com/

Any wisdom on this most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you have to attach the method to the googletag object. This may be as simple as removing the semicolon after the preceding line.

e.g.

```
googletag.defineSlot(‘/50217444/MomSnacks_728x90′, [728, 90], ‘div-gpt-ad-1427162132059-5′).addService(googletag.pubads())
.setCollapseEmptyDiv(true); //Collapsible div–Collapse this slot before ad fetch
```

if you are using the code suggested above, it will only collapse the ad slot the method is attached to.

If you want all ads to start collapsed and show up when populated, add the following to your < head> section of the page.

```
<script>
    googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(true);
</script>
```

Comment: OK...I really appreciate your help. Removing that extra semicolon did pop in the ads. I still have the issue of the mobile ads parking space. Any thoughts on how to make those not take up space on non mobile devices? There is a mobile ad below the banner, and two at the bottom of the sidebar. That is why there is white space. I need that not to show on non mobile.

Comment: I got this to work thanks to your help! I added the .setCollapseEmptyDiv(true); //Collapsible div–Collapse this slot before ad fetch to each seperate ad I wanted to collapse. Folds down perfectly now. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @user4759511 your welcome, i suggest accepting answer, this may help others in the future